# A query working on sql studio, but doesn't work on C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have this query and i get results when i execute it on Sql studio:

```
select TeamName, count(*) 
  from NetHoz_Decision
  inner join NetHoz_Case on NetHoz_Decision.CaseDisplayIdentifier = NetHoz_Case.CaseDisplayIdentifier 
  inner join maintik on MainTik.Counter = NetHoz_Case.TikCounter
  inner join Teams on MainTik.TeamCounter = Teams.Counter
  where NetHoz_Decision.DecisionStatusChangeDate between '2015-07-23' and '2015-07-28'
  group by TeamName
```

But when i execute it on C# SqlCommand I don't get any result.
The dataSet is empty and i don't get any error.
I thought the problem might be on date.
Am i converting it right?

```
String date1 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker1.Value);
String date2 = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: There's not enough context here. Normally you would use type-safe parameters and therefore not need to convert to string at all. Does it work (return results) without the `where` clause?

Comment: Have you looked at the command object's CommandText property and copied/pasted it into SQL Studio?  Also, are you actually using your date variables in the SQL itself?

Comment: @oscilatingcretin
I didn't think about the option of copying it back to sql. I removed the where clause and copied it to sql and it's working.
And yes, i'm realy using the date variables in the SQL itself.

Comment: You should be using parameters instead of literals for the date values. Note that `String.Format` and `DateTime.ToString` uses localized separators. Parameters of type DateTime (don't convert to string) will not have any issues with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.90).aspx) and [type-safe parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
const string query = "
select TeamName, count(*) 
 from NetHoz_Decision
 inner join NetHoz_Case on NetHoz_Decision.CaseDisplayIdentifier = NetHoz_Case.CaseDisplayIdentifier 
 inner join maintik on MainTik.Counter = NetHoz_Case.TikCounter
 inner join Teams on MainTik.TeamCounter = Teams.Counter
 where NetHoz_Decision.DecisionStatusChangeDate between @from and @to
 group by TeamName
";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", dateTimePicker1.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dateTimePicker2.Value.AddDays(1));
```